# Backup: daily backup changed files only to Amazon S3/Glacier

Tags: backup, amazon-web-services

I am using [this rsync bash script](http://www.howtogeek.com/175008/the-non-beginners-guide-to-syncing-data-with-rsync/) to create a daily backup of my webserver (only changed files). It works fine, daily backups are transferred to my home NAS. Only new/changed files are transferred, non-changed files are symlinked. So the daily transfer is really low.

I decided to make another backup, I choosed Amazon S3/or Glacier. Unfortunately This is where I need help. What would be the best way to upload daily backup to Amazon S3 like I do to my NAS? The rsync won't work here, since Amazon S3/Glacier needs special upload client.

Any help, other backup solution, provider recommendation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows computer you can consider Cloudberry Backup. They have a free version and it will allow you to back up your NAS to S3/Glacier. 
http://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup

Comment: Are you affiliated with this company?